# How to stop forwarding a port?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I was trying out local port forwarding and I used to following command:

```
ssh -L 8080:www.ubuntuforums.org:80 <host>
```

I want to change the address where 8080 is forwarded. Using the same command again results in an 'address in use' message and the action is refused. I have tried killing the process that is using 8080:

```
lsof -ti:8080 | xargs kill -9
```

I also tried restarting my SSH server and restarting my computer. After doing all this, if I browse to http://localhost:8080 I am forwarded to ubuntuforums.org.

How can I change this?

Apologies if another answer does exist. I already searched and the only other similar question I found also does not have an answer.

Comment: You restarted the computer on which you ran `ssh -L ...` or on the computer in which you SSHd into?

Comment: I simply exit ssh.

Comment: Yes, I restarted the computer that I ran that command on and I also tried exiting SSH.

Comment: Use `lsof -i :8080` to confirm your `kill` works. Check the parent process of `ssh -L` to see who is starting it on boot (or after being killed): `ps -f -pid [PID of ssh -L]`

Comment: Thanks @Wayne Vosberg. I used the first command to confirm the kill worked. When I tried creating another forward it all appeared to work until the browser directed to the old forward. It turns out the old forward had been cached and the new forward was not being accessed. Clearing the browser history and trying again gave me the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

The following command kills what is using the specified port.

```
lsof -ti:8080 | xargs kill -9
```

As pointed out in the comments, it can be helpful to check this command succeeded by using

```
lsof -i :8080
```

Keep in mind that the old forwarded port may still be cached by the browser and you may need to clear your browser history to see the new forwarded port.